# Create a Variable in GTM using objects in the dataLayer

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am wondering if it is possible to create a variable in GTM using the objects in the eCommerce dataLayer? Below is my script and I want to pass the products name in a variable.

```
<script>
gtm.data.ecommerce = {
    'detail' : {
        'actionField': {'list': gtm.list},
        'products': [{
            'name':         'productname',
            'id':           '123456',   ,
            'price':        '25.0',
            'brand':        'mybrand',
            'category':     'top',
            'list':         gtm.list
        }]
    },
    'impressions': []
}
```

Comment: Where is your variable coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some html that includes your product names (if you don't have it already). Then when those products are interacted with, by click for instance, send that product name to GTM.

```js
function sendToGTM (productName) {
  /**
   * send data to GTM
   */
  console.log(productName);
  var data = {
    'detail' : {
        'actionField': {'list': gtm.list},
        'products': [{
            'name':         productName,
            'id':           '123456',
            'price':        '25.0',
            'brand':        'mybrand',
            'category':     'top',
            'list':         gtm.list
        }]
    },
    'impressions': []
  };
  gtm.data.ecommerce = data;
  return data;
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  /**
   * on click, send product name to gtm function
   */
  if (event.target.classList.contains('product')) {
    sendToGTM(event.target.dataset.productName);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Create a Variable in GTM using objects in the dataLayer</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="products">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1131/711161806_fcf773a330_z.jpg?zz=1" class="product" data-product-name="Sunny" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://indianapublicmedia.org/news/files/2012/06/sun.jpg" class="product" data-product-name="Bright Sun" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://mediad.publicbroadcasting.net/p/kbia/files/styles/medium/public/hot%20summer%20sun_jetsandzeppelins_Flickr.jpg" class="product" data-product-name="Sun Shiney Day" />
    </a>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```